# How to execute sails js in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, sails.js

I am using docker for my sails js project. Any idea how to check which command was used to run sails.js. I have tried History command but its not giving me previous command which was run

Can anybody tell me how to check the which command was used before to execute the sailsjs? I need to restart my sails.js

Comment: `docker stop` and `docker start`?

Comment: @cricket_007 , But it will stop docker only not sails js

Comment: No... That stops the container that would be running sails... In order to "restart sails" you must restart the container. In any case, why can't you just look at the Dockerfile for the `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to see what is being ran? Can you show your Dockerfile?

Comment: Which base image are you using and if you are installing sails js through Dockerfile, please provide ..

Answer (score 1):

To check what command used to run to make it started in docker, try

`docker ps -a --no-trunc --format "{{.ID}}: {{.Command}}"`

It will show the full command for sailsjs for the container.